# How to automatically generate a label for each item in a for loop using CTkInter

Tags: python

I have a function that I have been using at my work to rename an entire folder of files. I am now trying to implement a GUI so my coworkers can use the same function (I work in accounting so no one has even heard of programming). I figure that printing the outputs of the function to a scrollable window would be better than a progress bar so people can visually see that a file has been renamed.

How would I create a label for every iteration of the loop, and then output that to a scrollable frame?

I didn't include the actual function I am using, but here is an example of what I have tried to implement on a more simple level.

```
def printer():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        #insert label(i) = CTkLabel(scrollable_frame, text = "output of function")
        #label(i).pack()

button = CTkButton(window, text="step",command=printer)
button.pack()

scrollable_frame = CTkScrollableFrame(window, width=200, height=200)
scrollable_frame.pack()
```

I am pretty new to programming (1 month) and have heard of classes so maybe that is what I need to use?